# mailer.send(mimetype='text/html') does not work along with "attachs" - Scrapy

Tags: scrapy, gmail, html-email

I am creating CSV files and sending as an attachment in email via Gmail SMTP

Here is related code in Scrapy 1.5.1

```
mailer = MailSender(smtphost='smtp.gmail.com', 
                mailfrom='noreply@domain.io', 
                smtpuser='email@gmail.com', 
                smtppass='PASS', smtpport=587)


attachs.append(("file.csv", "text/csv", csv_buffer))

self.mailer.send(
                to=self.mailto,
                mimetype='text/html',
                subject="Crawler to scrape RELATED domains finished",
                body="Please <b>download</b> attached files<br /><br />Crawler Stats<br />" ,
                attachs=attachs
            )
```

I simply get raw/unrendered HTML in mail instead of rendered.

If I remove `attachs` param from `send` then I get rendered email

I also tried

```
attachs.append(("file.csv", "text/html", csv_buffer))
```

but still I get raw html instead of rendered one.

Comment: I can't really see what the issue would be with your question either, but sometimes people downvote because they don't like the question (and not because the question is of bad quality) and it doesn't cost any of their rep.

Comment: I rose an issue to Scrapinghub here https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/3439 and they confirmed that its not yet supported ... (I am still searching for people who down-voted me)